# How to create NGINX debian package from souce?

Tags: 14.04, nginx

I want to create a NGINX .deb package from the source. Can anyone guide me through.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Very painfully, if you are starting from scratch.  Mind if I ask why you want to though?  I have PPAs with more updated versions of nginx available (I also maintain the package in Ubuntu)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably looking for `checkinstall` https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CheckInstall

What you do is you follow the instructions for compiling the application you want (in this case NGINX).

Then when you get to the step that tells you to issue the `make install` command, you replace it with `checkinstall`.

This compiles the code into deb packages you can install with `dpkg -i packagenamehere.deb`

Don't distribute these packages to others though, as they are built specifically for your machine, with the dependencies based on packages already installed on your PC.

That said, you can uninstall them, just like you would any other deb package :)

Also, you can give them version numbers to upgrade an existing version you had compiled earlier.

Good luck!

Comment: Tread lightly though - nginx is a fickle beast to build.

Comment: Agreed.  This is the tutorial I've used in the past, as I like playing with the RTMP module. https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module - I just substitute the `make install` line, and it places a group of deb packages in the source directory.  You can install them one at a time, it'll tell you if one of the others needs to be installed first.

Comment: Also, it uses non Ubuntu/Debian compliant file and folder placement.  Instead of using the `/var/www/html` folder, it uses something like `/usr/lib/nginx/html` when compiled from source

Comment: Actually that's compliant file placement for non-packages. (should be /usr/local/... but still relatively compliant).  In the nginx package in the PPA and Ubuntu, we use the postinstall scripts to create/copy default to /var/www.

Comment: Oh, did not know that.  Learn something new every day :)